# return from controller view and variables to js

Tags: javascript, laravel, view, controller, return

In `VersusController@show` I return view:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    return view('versus.results', compact('common_matches'));
}
```

And then I add this view to table #results:

```
$('#manager1_id,#manager2_id').on('change', function() {

      $.ajax({
          type    : 'GET',
          url     : '{{action('VersusController@show')}}',
          data:{
              manager1_id    :   $('#manager1_id').val(),
              manager2_id    :   $('#manager2_id').val()
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $("#results").find('tbody').empty().append(data);
          }
      });

  } );
```

How I can return from controller view and variables to JS? Something like this:

```
return [view('versus.results', compact('common_matches')),  $variable1, $variable2, ...];
```

Comment: What is common_matches?

Comment: $common_matches = Match::all()->get();

Comment: @IgorOstapiuk you can return a json instead, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a json like that:

```
return response()->json(['html' => view('versus.results',compact('common_matches'))->render(), 'variableX' => $variableX]);
```

So update your js:
$('#manager1_id,#manager2_id').on('change', function() {

```
  $.ajax({
      type    : 'GET',
      url     : '{{action('VersusController@show')}}',
      data:{
          manager1_id    :   $('#manager1_id').val(),
          manager2_id    :   $('#manager2_id').val()
      },
      dataType: 'json'
      success: function(data) {
          $("#results").find('tbody').empty().append(data.html);
          var variableX = data.variableX;
          //do stuffs
      }
  });
```

} );